# How long does an email stay in Queue for Triggered Send Interaction?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

When a Triggered Send Interaction is in a paused state, new requests will be held in a queue. Is there a shelf-life for that queue? Or will emails remain there indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the [April 2018 SFMC](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_april_2018_platform.htm&type=5) update, Triggered Send queue life is 14 days. After that they will expire and will not be able to be processed.

[image]

---

**Edit** This is old info according to @eazye and @naveenvm and the new number as of [June 2018](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2018_ts_expiration.htm&type=5) is 3 days before expiry.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, thanks for the info. How about this one, which is June 2018 Release, it states if the difference to be more than 3 days, when the triggered send messages that have not been processed or sent within the expiration period-  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2018_ts_expiration.htm&type=5. Is this different?

Comment: I think the difference is unprocessed versus processed. The above is for the queue to get into the Trigger, where the one you reference is for after they have been processed and are in the send queue. As usual, SFMC is very detailed in their documentation, so its completely crystal clear what they intended to share. (sarcasm) I could be wrong, I am just sharing my interpretation of those detailed 2 sentences...

Comment: They will error after three days

Comment: @EazyE So pause queue will last 14 days, but processed queue will error after 3 days? Or just even if paused, if they are in queue for 3 days, it will expire? I have seen the 14 day expiry, but never experienced the 3 day one on my TSDs before.

Comment: Unsure what the question is in April when it was first introduced it was 14 days, by June it was modified to 3 days. So a message can sit in the queue forever, but when the TS is resumed any message over three days old will error and not be sent. all messages under three days will be sent

Comment: Interesting. I have experienced a 14 day queue expiry but not a 3 day one. I have had triggers paused for over 3 days send as normal when restarted but after 14 days they just disappear from the queue

Comment: Not trying to dispute. Just interesting to me. Gonna have to take a look and test. Maybe the accts had custom business rules

Comment: They erred messages should appear in the error column

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question so raised a case with salesforce and  got the following answer:
"If a subscriber is in the queue for > 3 days, when the job is resumed they will go to error, which can be exported through the not sent report

If the subscriber is in the queue > 14 days they will be deprecated from the queue even while the send is currently paused. and there is no reporting available for these contacts

So the queue will not have any subscriber older then 14 days, and when its processed any older than 3 days will go to error status"