# emails in Queue - Triggered Send Interaction

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I'm not sure what happening with emails that were in queue when trigger send was paused. I've found the information that if emails were in queue no longer than 3 days they will be send, and if it be over 3 days not. Is it true?

Comment: Can you share the link to where you have found this information?

Comment: it was here. In comments. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305292/how-long-does-an-email-stay-in-queue-for-triggered-send-interaction

Comment: ok, I've found another source that says "When you restart a triggered send, subscribers older than 3 days in the queue will error out. Only for subscribers who are in the queue for less than 72 hours, a resend is attempted." but how can I export emails that were errored ? I don't see them in sendLog.

Comment: not sent extract